# ReportViewer Local report have a cache ? Impossible to replace old report

Tags: report-viewer2010, report-viewer2012, report-viewer2016

I have an application using ReportViewer set up with local report.
I edited a report and replaced the original.
Despite this the application on the production PC continues to generate the report with the old model. Even if I delete the rdlc file altogether it still continues to generate the report even though the report no longer exists.
Is there a cache? If yes, how can I clean it up? Or how can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the cache but a setting in the properties of the ReportViewer WindowsForms control.
In particular, the ReportPath property was not set in this specific report, so the default ReportEmbeddedResource property was used. This resulted in the report being embedded within the assembly